# Why i'm getting ":app:mergeReleaseResources" error when i try to create release APK?

Tags: react-native

The problem is, when i try to create the release apk for publishing it to Play Store, there occurs an error like below,

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'
```

and there're a bunch of "Duplicate Resources" errors as follows,

```
drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png       [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_splash_image] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_splash_image.jpeg        [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_splash_image] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_splash_image.jpeg: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_productbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_productbg.jpg       [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_productbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_productbg.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativepaper_src_assets_backchevron.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_864] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_864.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_864] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_864.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_textbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_textbg.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_textbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_textbg.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_qrcodescan] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_qrcodescan.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_qrcodescan] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_qrcodescan.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_siparisonay] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_siparisonay.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_siparisonay] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_siparisonay.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_topbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_topbg.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_topbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_topbg.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backiconmask.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_product] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_product.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_product] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_product.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_cardbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_cardbg.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/src_assets_images_cardbg] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_assets_images_cardbg.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png     [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /Users/eaidy/Projects/Coffeco-Ata/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
```

I've been struggling trying to find a solution for all day, if there's a solution for this problem i'd be really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because of duplicate drawables dirs on android/app/src/main/res/. Just delete the drawable-* dirs `rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*` and try to create apk again.

Hope it helps!